# $X, Y$ i.i.d and $h \in C^0 (\mathbb{R}, [a,b]) \implies \operatorname{Cov}(X,h(X)) = \operatorname{Cov}(Y,h(Y))$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a basic question about i.i.d random variables:

> Given $X, Y$ i.i.d, $h \in C^0 (\mathbb{R}, [a,b])$, why is it true that $\operatorname{Cov}(X,h(X)) = \operatorname{Cov}(Y,h(Y))$?

I saw it used in some proof, tried showing by definition but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: No need to be depend. If $X$ and $Y$ has the same distribution, $\mathbb E[f(X)]=\mathbb E[f(Y)]$ for all bounded and measurable function $f$.

Comment: @Surb how does that prove it? I think I need to show that $\mathbb{E}[Xh(X)]=\mathbb{E}[Yh(Y)]$

Comment: No, this is just a very basic result of measure theory... if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are measures s.t. $\mu=\nu$ (i.e. $\mu(A)=\nu(A)$ for all measurable sets $A$), then of course $\int f\,\mathrm d \mu=\int f\,\mathrm d \nu$ for all mesurable function $f$.

Comment: I haven't studied measure theory, there is no need to be condescending. 
I am just asking how to show what I asked, by the definition:
$Cov(X,Y) = \mathbb{E}((X-\mathbb{E}(X))((Y-\mathbb{E}(Y))=\mathbb{E}(XY)-\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y).$

Comment: Sorry if you had the impression that my previous comment was arrogant, it was really not the case. Without measure theory, (and depending on your definition of the expectation), it can be very hard to prove (unless if $X$ or $Y$ are discrete or continuous). As you wrote the statement (because of the very few informations you gave on what $X$ and $Y$ are neither a possible definition of how you define expectation), it's not obvious to guess that you don't have some basic knowledge on measure theory.